# Why edit is not working even code is correct

Tags: django

when I click on update, it is not updating. I don't know what to do. Everything is working except edit.

**views.py:**

```
def addnew(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = BookForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/')  
            except:  
                pass 
    else:  
        form = BookForm()  
    return render(request,'book/index.html',{'form':form})

def index(request):  
    books = Book.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"book/show.html",{'books':books})

def edit(request, id):  
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'book/edit.html',{'book':book})

def update(request, id):  
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = BookForm(request.POST,instance=book)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'book/edit.html',{'book': book})

def destroy(request, id):  
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)  
    book.delete()  
    return redirect("/")
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from book import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),  
    path('addnew',views.addnew),  
    path('edit/<int:id>',views.edit),  
    path('update/<int:id>',views.update),  
    path('delete/<int:id>',views.destroy),
]
```

**templates/books:**
**edit.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-12">  
   <form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{ book.id }}">  
     {% csrf_token %}  
    <div class="container">  
   <br>  

    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <h3>Update Details</h3>  
    </div>  
     </div>  

    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book Id:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id_id" required maxlength="20" value="{{book.id}}"/>
    </div>  
     </div>  

     <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book Name:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="id_name" required maxlength="100" value="{{book.book_name}}" />  
    </div>  
     </div>    
 
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>  
    </div>  
     </div>  
    </div>  
   </form>
   {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
           
      <form method="post" class="post-form" action="/addnew">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
       <div class="container">  
      <br>  
       <div class="form-group row">  
       <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">  
       <!-- <h3>Enter Details</h3>   -->
       </div>  
        </div>  
        
        <div class="form-group row">  
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book Name:</label>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">  
         {{ form.book_name }}  
       </div>  
        </div>   
       <div class="form-group row">  
       <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">  
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>  
       </div>  
        </div>  
       </div>  
      </form>  
     </div>
     {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**show.html:**

```
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <body>
 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>Book Records</h4> <span><a href="/addnew" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Book</a></span>
                        <br>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="90%">
                            <thead>
                                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Book Name</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for book in books %}  
                    <tr>  
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                    <td>{{ book.id }}</td>  
                    <td>{{ book.book_name }}</td> 
                    <td><a href="/edit/{{book.id}}"><span style="color:brown;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
                    <td><a href="/delete/{{book.id}}"><span style="color:brown;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td>  
                    </tr>  
                {% endfor %} 
                </tbody>
                        
                </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#bootstrapdatatable').DataTable({     
                    "aLengthMenu": [[3, 5, 10, 25, -1], [3, 5, 10, 25, "All"]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 3
                    } 
                );
            } );
            </script>
        
        </body>    
</body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here, edit is not working. when I click on update, it is not updating. I don't know what to do. Everything is working except edit.
please anyone tell me what to do.
I have tried several times.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from book.models import Book
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Book
        fields = ['book_name']
        widgets = { 'book_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' })}
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

    class Book(models.Model):  
        book_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
        class Meta:  
            db_table = "book"
```

Comment: Probably your form is not valid. Can you share the "BookForm" code and the "Book" model class?

Comment: i have added form and model

Comment: Please, consider following the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The emphasis here is on "minimal". If this doesn't help you locate the source of the problem and solve it yourself, it will help you improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template of your form is wrong. Pay attention that your form is waiting for you to send it a field called book_name:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Book
        fields = ['book_name']
        widgets = { 'book_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' })}
```

However, in the template you are sending it the id field and a field called name:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id_id" required maxlength="20" value="{{book.id}}"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="id_name" required maxlength="100" value="{{book.book_name}}" />
```

So, according your forms.py, you must to change the template like this:

```
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{ book.id }}">  
{% csrf_token %}  
<div class="container">  
<br>  
<div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <h3>Update Details</h3>  
  </div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book Name:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_name" id="id_book_name" required maxlength="100" value="{{book.book_name}}" />  
</div>  
 </div>    
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>  
</div>  
 </div>  
</div>
```

BTW, you could simplify all of this, using the power of Django like this:

```
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{ book.id }}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>
</form>
```

You should study the way in witch Django builds forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: problem is only when i click on update button it is not redirecting to the books page. root is    books/

Comment: According to your code, if form is valid, you will be redirect to the root of the app: "return redirect('/')" You can change this on your code.